# parse a text file and put the output as a filename

Tags: scripting, batch-file, filenames

I have a tricky problem: there is a file (version.txt) that contains two lines with version numbers. I parsed this with

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (c:\install\version.txt) DO @echo %i`

but now the plan is to put the output as a filename and add the computername in 
front, like

`%computername%_contens-from-version-file.txt`

can someone help me?

thanks 
uwe

Comment: A simple `echo %computername%%i.txt` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET MAJOR=
SET MINOR=
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (c:\install\version.txt) DO (
  IF "!MAJOR!" == "" (
    SET MAJOR=%%i
  ) ELSE (
    IF "!MINOR!" == "" SET MINOR=%%i
  )
)
ECHO Version is %MAJOR%.%MINOR%
SET computername=just_example
SET FILENAME=%computername%%MAJOR%.%MINOR%.txt
ECHO File name is %FILENAME%
ECHO File contents>"c:\install\%FILENAME%"
```

Comment: thanks, the output is ok. but i need a new file with the computername and this output as filename :)

Comment: this works ECHO.>c:\install\%computername%_%MAJOR%--%MINOR%.txt but in the version.txt is a space, so the new filename is cut at this location :(

Comment: thanks, it works. is it possible to use a set parameter (ZENWORKS_HOME=C:\Program Files\Novell\ZENworks) instead of c:\install\version.txt? it contains a space in the path and so the output is incomplete

Comment: If a file name contains space(s), it should be surrounded by double-quotes. It would be a good practice to always double-quote file names if the name can be vary. e.g.: "My File.txt" or "C:\My Data\My File.txt" or "%ZENWORKS_HOME%\%FILENAME%"

Comment: yes, but it works only with the usebackq option in the for /f command

Comment: how can i parse the whole version.txt if it contains more than two lines?

Comment: The code within the `FOR...DO` parenthesis will be executed for each line in the given file (always one line at a time by design). You'll have to make conditions to make specific code is executed for specific line number like the above `IF...THEN...ELSE` example. e.g.: add another `ELSE...` for `IF "!MINOR!" == ""...` if the third line is the build number. You can also use a variable to set incrementally (via `SET /A`) to be used at later code which must be run at specific line number.